# C++ Multiple parameter with cin

Tags: c++

This is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNumbers(int x, int y, int z, int a) {
  int result = x + y + z + a;
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  cout << addNumbers(1, 7, 8, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

And i just testing my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNumbers(int x, int y, int z, int a) {
  int result = x + y + z + a;
  return result;
}

int main() {
      int x,y,z,a;
      int result = x + y + z + a;
      cin >> result;
      return 0;
    }
```

Im just new in C++, i was wondering if it's possible to use input (cin) to add a value inside (x,y,z,a) variables and add it using result = x+y+z+a;

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: First of all this code wont compile, as you have not defined the variables x, y,z,a

Comment: the original code x,y,z,a have their own value in int main().. i was trying to change the scenario by applying cin (to input 4 numbers then add it)

Comment: ohhh. got it... please check my answer below.

Comment: Sorry for bad English, i was trying to input 4 value in each datatype and names in parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have trying to scan multiple variables. So, Use:

```
cin>>x>>y>>z>>a;
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNumbers(int x, int y, int z, int a) {
  int result = x + y + z + a;
  return result;
}

int main() {
int x,y,z,a;
cin>>x>>y>>z>>a;
int result = addNumbers(x,y,z,a);
cout<<result<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am studying C++ in sololearn apps and i tried to run your code, it gives me an error

`..\Playground\: In function 'int main()': 
..\Playground\:11:12: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token 
int main() { 
            ^ 
..\Playground\:18:1: error: expected '}' at end of input 
} 
^`

Comment: @Chipshot This is your  sololearn apps issue, please check another compiler.

Comment: oh sorry about that will try another compiler, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think you need,

```
cin >> x >> y >> z >> a;
```